# CRM 2011 progress indicator in forms

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some javascript that fires when a form loads, and the javascript can takes up to 10 seconds (queries an external service for some data). Is there any way to show some sort of a visual progress indicator or spinning wheel or something similar to let the user know that there's a process still running in the background? I've done this before with just showing/hiding divs in html, but I don't think I can apply that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how you do that in the past, but you can do this using jquery. You can check [here](http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.pt/2011/09/crm-2011-ajax-loading-message-screen.html) a example of that kind of implementation.

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I wanted.